# Spark: How to write org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have an RDD that has the signature

```
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream]
```

In this RDD, each row has its own partition.

This ByteArrayOutputStream is zip output. I am applying some processing on the data in each partition and i want to export the processed data from each partition as a single zip file. What is the best way to export each Row in the final RDD as one file per row on hdfs?

If you are interested in knowing how I ended up with such an Rdd.

```
val npyData = transformedTopData.select("tokenIDF", "topLevelId").rdd.repartition(2).mapPartitions(x => {
      val vectors = for {
        row <- x
      } yield {
        row.getAs[Vector](0)
      }
      Seq(ml2npyCSR(vectors.toSeq).zipOut)
    }.iterator)
```

EDIT: Count works perfectly fine

```
scala> npyData.count()
res9: Long = 2
```

Comment: Have you tried to `count` it? I doubt the RDD is gonna work.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Count works fine. updated the output in question

Comment: What is `ml2npyCSR.zipOut` doing?

Comment: Right. It will work but when you try to access the "records" of type `java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream` it may not.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov it's taking all the records in the partition, creates a csr matrix in npz format. In simple we can assume it is similar to zipping the rows with in each partition

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Yes of course. That's the reason why I asked this question. It's the ByteArrayStream that backs ZipOuputStream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I should represent my data as PairRDD and implement a custom [FileOutputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileOutputFormat.html). I looked in to the implementation of SequenceFileOutputFormat for inspiration and managed to write my own version based on that.

My custom FileOutputFormat is available [here](https://github.com/vumaasha/ml2npy/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/github/vumaasha/ml2npy/hadoop/NpyOutPutFormat.scala)

Answer (score 0):

Spark has very little support for file system operations. You'll need to Hadoop FileSystem API to create individual files

```
// This method is needed as Hadoop conf object is not serializable
def createFileStream(pathStr:String) = {
    import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
    import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
    import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

    val hadoopconf = new Configuration();
    val fs = FileSystem.get(hadoopconf);
    val outFileStream = fs.create(new Path(pathStr));
    outFileStream
}

// Method writes to individual files. 
// Needs a unique id along with object for output file naming
def writeToFile( x:(Char, Long) ) : Unit = {
    val (dataStream, id) = x
    val output_dir = "/tmp/del_a/"
    val outFileStream = createFileStream(output_dir+id)
    dataStream.writeTo(outFileStream)
    outFileStream.close()
}


// zipWithIndex used for creating unique id for each item in rdd
npyData.zipWithIndex().foreach(writeToFile)
```

Reference:
[Hadoop FileSystem example](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopDfsReadWriteExample)
[ByteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(java.io.OutputStream)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#writeTo(java.io.OutputStream))

Comment: Though this would work, I found the right way of doing this, which I explain in my answer below